# How to flash Official ROM on SAMSUNG GALAXY S6 EDGE

Tags: samsung, rom

I was offered a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge a few months ago and I discovered over time that applications installed themselves on my phone and performed operations in the background and my ins such as activate the microphone , play music or send sms. I tried several factory values ​​reset but nothing changes, each time I have the internet connection activated they reinstall completely. This has the effect of heating my phone and reducing the life of the battery.

So I decided to flash my phone with an Official ROM that I did on SamMobile But when I launched the flash with Odin and my phone in download mode the operation failed!

I haven't been able to solve this problem for months already that's why I come here to ask for your help.

when the flash fails, my phone displays the error "SECURE CHECK FAIL: (BOOTLOADER)

I would like to make some clarifications:
- my phone is an SM-G925F (This is what is written behind it is also what is displayed in the settings)
- In download mode I rather see Product: name SM-G925L
- in the developer option, I don't find the "Unlock OEM" button
- When I click on "Software update" in my phone, nothing happens
- I don't know if it's important to specify it but I live in Cameroon

I need help please!

[image: before flash fail]

Comment: One potential reason for the error message could be that you are trying to flash the wrong firmware image (which has the wrong signature what makes the signature/security check to fail). Sometimes there are multiple versions of the same phone available e.g. for different countries. Make sure you have the correct firmware (may be you have to try different versions out). Based on other discussions the model number shown in download mode is the correct model number, the other model name is manipulated.

Comment: If the model number displayed in download mode is correct, why is it different from the one written on the back of the phone? Which ROM should I try now? the SM-G925L or another variant of the SM-G925F?

Comment: May be the SM-G925L version was cheaper or better available (version for Latin America, India, Australia) and the it got re-flashed with the global firmware of SM-G925F. I am also not sure if the SM-G925F on the backside is genuine. The Bootloader is the only think you can't forge that easily, hence it stills shows the original model number (and this is the firmware you have to use or you could try to flash the international version skipping the botloader).

Comment: you must flash SM-G925L of course. if not available on sammobile or updato, flash SM-G925F with modded odin

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that, if using Windows, there's a tool called "Frija" which you can use to download firmware directly from Samsung's servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flashed an SM-G925L and it worked except that the SM-G925L that I found on SamMobile was all designed for South Korea and for LG U+ So every time I turn on my samsung a beautiful LG logo is displayed but everything works correctly and I got rid of malware!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you Galaxy S6 Edge may have been rooted as I see current binary and system status are indicated as custom and that would explain not being able to OTA update.  I also know that some unlocked refurbished phone replace motherboards as long as the hardware fits.  Its my understanding that what is displayed in the download mode, i,n this case "G925L", will be the correct variant when choosing the proper firmware.
  I've rooted every Samsung I have ever owned and have never had the issues you described prior to factory reset.  It is my humble option that your phone may have been compromise  and suggest your change all your password accounts.  It would be easier is you did this after a successful boot rather than before as you'll face Google FRP lock.   Good luck